# Activate a Sencha Touch tab from a custom JS function

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a Cordova project on iOS and I want to switch to a specific tab following an event 'X'.

Assuming event 'X' just occurred, my objective C makes the following call to run a JS function `openNotificationTab()` like so:

```
NSString *goToNotification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"openNotificationTab()"];
[viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:goToNotification];
```

The `openNotificationTab()` function resides in filename.js and I verified it is within scope and accessible by testing with an `alert()`.

Now the definition for my js function is as follows:

```
function openNotificationTab(){
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({
    xtype: 'notificationtabview'
    });
}
```

The problem is that this function opens the correct panel, but overlays it on top of everything else. So the entire tab menu is no longer visibile and thus inaccessible.

I also tried

```
"Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(1)" and  "Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('notificationtabview')"
```

but neither does anything. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call setActiveItem on your TabPanel, with either the index of the tab that you want to show, or the item you want to show.

You can check the class of your viewport with:

```
Ext.Viewport.$className
```

You will probably learn here that the viewport is not your tab panel.

```
var tabPanel = Ext.Viewport.down("tabpanel");
tabPanel.setActiveItem(tabPanel.down("notificationtabview"))
```

or

```
var tabPanel = Ext.Viewport.down("tabpanel");
tabPanel.setActiveItem(1)
```

both works.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Claude.